# listview item not working in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

excuse my english ,i am new in android and create app . every thing work fine but i have very small problem is that in Navigation Drawer when i click on item is just Navigation Drawer be closed thats it no ERROR no ANY thing wrong on logcat Really i have no idea but i guess mybe from layout .
my layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/container"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           tools:context=".MyPayamak"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="10sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tt"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"/>

      </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/bar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="کاربر میهمان"
            android:textColor="#3D3D3D"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/ShowFakenameOfUser"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/usericon"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and another thing my Navigation Drawer code is same in all activity and work fine but 2 activity have this problem uses this layout .

in my oncreate have this code :

```
mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();



    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("ورود")) {
                Intent it = new Intent(List_Payamak_ha.this, loginUser.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("ثبت نام")){
                Intent it = new Intent(List_Payamak_ha.this, RegisterUser.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("کاربران فعال")) {
                Intent it = new Intent(List_Payamak_ha.this, ActiveUsers.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("کاربران برتر")) {
                Intent it = new Intent(List_Payamak_ha.this, TopUsers.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("درباره نرم افزار")) {
                Intent it = new Intent(List_Payamak_ha.this, AboutPage.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("خروج")) {
                int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }
    });


    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();
```

whole code :

```
    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] osArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.SlideMenu);
        mAdapterCopy = new MenuSideAdapterItem(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                R.id.textViewMenuSide,
                osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapterCopy);

    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("منو");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }


            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private class MenuSideAdapterItem extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MenuSideAdapterItem(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View Row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item,parent,false);
            String[] items =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.SlideMenu);

            ImageView IconView = (ImageView) Row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMenuSide);
            TextView textMenuSide = (TextView) Row.findViewById(R.id.textViewMenuSide);
            textMenuSide.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Far_TitrDF.ttf"));

            textMenuSide.setText(items[position]);

            if (items[position].equalsIgnoreCase("ورود")){
                IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.loginicon);
            }else if (items[position].equalsIgnoreCase("ثبت نام")){
                IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.registericoon);
            }else if (items[position].equalsIgnoreCase("کاربران فعال")){
                IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.activeuser);
            }else if (items[position].equalsIgnoreCase("کاربران برتر")){
                IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.topuser);
            }else if (items[position].equalsIgnoreCase("درباره نرم افزار")){
                IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.about);
            }else if (items[position].equalsIgnoreCase("خروج")){
                IconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.exit);
            }
            return Row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @m iav -  listview item not clickable when i click on listview just closed Navigation Drawer !

Comment: You mean your click has no effect other than closing the drawer? How are you managing click events on the ListView? Show your activity code.

Comment: yes i use same code in another activity its work .

Comment: In eclipse or studio create new project with navigation drawer(asked when creating new project) and then try to add your code in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was from another fragment, uses for show image on bottom of screen , fragment was on top drawer when i click on drawer actually was i click on Fragment so i never hit on buttons since i replace `fragment` with `RelativeLayout` and solve my problem .

Answer (score 1):

in your case its really bad idea use `fragment` but now you can use [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) and this [tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think control is not going in your if conditions so do as follow

1 print message in each if statement using

```
Log.i("tag","any_message");
```

or

```
System.out.println("any_message");
```

2 Also print add else statement with proper message

and check your logcat  by this way you will come to know whether control is going inside if statement or not.

Comment: done that befor sir but still not working its skip setOnItemClickListener  and i try android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false" each parent layout